# How to tune a guitar using harmonics?

Tags: guitar, tuning, harmonics

Suppose I want to tune my guitar, and

- I don't want to use a tuning device (e.g. I don't have it)
- I don't want to tune by equalizing an open string with a fretted string (e.g. because I fear that fretting makes the sound sharper than it should be)

So I'll equalize two open strings, using harmonics.

What is the best way for doing this? Are there any considerations that could make one way the best, or another?

- Which pairs of strings and which harmonics should I equalize? I use 4th and 3rd harmonics for strings 2&1, 4&3, 5&4, 6&5; and then, 3rd harmonic and basic tone for strings 5&1, 6&2. This works, but it surely can be improved.
- Where should I strike the string(s) to make the harmonics most suitable for tuning?
- Does the type of the guitar and/or strings make a difference?

Comment: Anatoly - this is already covered. And please remember to only ask one question at a time.

Comment: Note that if fretting the string makes it slightly sharp, then you still want to tune to that, since you want your fretted notes to be in tune along with your open notes. There's no such thing as perfect intonation so it will be a compromise no matter what. You might as well try to have the 5th fret in tune, if not the 10th or 17th.

Comment: The answer is actually [here](http://music.stackexchange.com/a/3080/3032)